# Freemarker, is it possible to set computer numbering format by default?

Tags: java, freemarker

About [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/), is it possible to instruct it to treat all numbers as "computer" ones by default?

I tried to apply

```
cfg.setSetting(Configurable.NUMBER_FORMAT_KEY, "computer");
```

or

```
cfg.setNumberFormat("computer");
```

to configuration object, but the outcome is not the desired. Believing this is the documentation's way to do it, is there anything wrong?

Comment: agree with you, it should work based on docs. http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_config_settings.html and http://freemarker.org/docs/api/freemarker/template/Configuration.html#setSetting-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Comment: cfg.setNumberFormat("computer"); is working as per desire in 2.3.21 version

Answer (score 2):

The number format you specify must be something that `java.text.DecimalFormat` supports. The closest thing you can do right now is switching the locale to `en_US` (and better ensure that it doesn't use groping; see http://freemarker.org/docs/app_faq.html#faq_number_grouping). Or, of course, you can write `?c`-s all over, but I suppose that's what you wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
cfg.setNumberFormat("#");
```

It worked for me

Comment: Cannot check answer, too many years and codebases away. If it worked for anyone else, plz ping to accept as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [docs](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_config_settings.html) it is possible to set it on Freemarker `Configuration` object.

Typical functional spring context initialization:

```
<bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
    <property name="templateLoaderPaths">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:META-INF/templates</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="freemarkerSettings">
        <props>
            <prop key="number_format">computer</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".ftl" />
    <property name="cache" value="true" />
    <property name="contentType" value="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <property name="requestContextAttribute" value="request" />
</bean>
```

Notice that number_format (or numberFormat for newer version of freemarker) is set to `FreeMarkerConfigurer`.

To your question... My guess is you set it to wrong config object or scope.

Answer (score 0):

It is worked in the latest version, I can do this in my Spring boot application

`freeMarkerConfigurer.getConfiguration().setNumberFormat("computer");`